# resize "box" in Java

Tags: html, css

I started high school this year, we are doing some big semestral project and I'm not very good in HTLM/CSS.

My crewmate did the page design on some random website, I copied the HTML to not lose time and it kinda works (still have to do a lot, centralizing the info, spacing the "blocks" etc).

The problem here is that I had to add a register button that was not on the page sent to me, I thought it will be easy because it's just ctrl C, and ctrl V but the HTML is not very organized and I have a tight deadline so I looking for help here.

(If u want to help me with the centralization also would be great but the register button is more important)[image]

```css
/*@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:wght@400;700&display=swap');*/

* {
    margin: 0px; 
    padding: 0px; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
  
html, head {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Ubuntu-bold;
} 

a {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.7;
    color: #666666;
    margin: 0px;
    transition: all 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
}
  
a:focus {
    outline: none !important;
}
  
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #403866;
}
  h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    margin: 0px;
}
  
p {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.7;
    color: #666666;
    margin: 0px;
}
  
ul, li {
    margin: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

input {
    outline: none;
    border: none;
}
  
textarea {
    outline: none;
    border: none;
}
  
textarea:focus, input:focus {
    border-color: transparent !important;
}
  
input::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #8f8fa1;}
input:-moz-placeholder { color: #8f8fa1;}
input::-moz-placeholder { color: #8f8fa1;}
input:-ms-input-placeholder { color: #8f8fa1;}
  
textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #8f8fa1;}
textarea:-moz-placeholder { color: #8f8fa1;}
textarea::-moz-placeholder { color: #8f8fa1;}
textarea:-ms-input-placeholder { color: #8f8fa1;}
  
label {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
}

button {
    outline: none !important;
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
}
  
button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
  
iframe {
    border: none !important;
}

.txt1 {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #827ffe;
    line-height: 1.4;
}
  
.limiter {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
  
.container-100 {
    width: 100%;  
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center !important;
    align-items: center !important;
    padding: 15px;
    
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;;
}
  
  
.wrap-login100 {
    width: 390px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
   
.login100-form {
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu-bold', sans-serif;
}
  
.login100-form-title {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu-bold', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #403866;
    line-height: 1.2;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
  
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
   
.wrap-input100 {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.input100 {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    color: #403866;
    line-height: 1.2;
    font-size: 18px;
  
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    height: 62px;
    padding: 0 20px 0 38px;
}

.focus-input100 {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: calc(100% + 2px);
    height: calc(100% + 2px);
    top: -1px;
    left: -1px;
    pointer-events: none;
    border: 1px solid #827ffe;
    border-radius: 3px;
  
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
  
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
    transition: all 0.4s;
  
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1.1) scaleY(1.3);
    -moz-transform: scaleX(1.1) scaleY(1.3);
    -ms-transform: scaleX(1.1) scaleY(1.3);
    -o-transform: scaleX(1.1) scaleY(1.3);
    transform: scaleX(1.1) scaleY(1.3);
}
  
.input100:focus + .focus-input100 {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
  
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}
  
.eff-focus-selection {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
  
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}

.input-checkbox100 {
    display: none;
}
  
.label-checkbox100 {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #999999;
    line-height: 1.2;
  
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 26px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
  
.label-checkbox100::before {
    content: "\f00c";
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: transparent;
  
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #827ffe;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
  
.input-checkbox100:checked + .label-checkbox100::before {
    color: #827ffe;
}

.container-login100-form-btn {
    width: 100%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
  
.login100-form-btn {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 1.2;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 20px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 62px;
    background-color: #827ffe;
    border-radius: 3px;
  
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
    transition: all 0.4s;
}
  
.login100-form-btn:hover {
    background-color: #403866;
}

.container-register100-form-btn {
    width: 100%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
  
.register100-form-btn {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 1.2;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 20px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 62px;
    background-color: #827ffe;
    border-radius: 3px;
  
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
    transition: all 0.4s;
}

.register100-form-btn:hover {
    background-color: #403866;
}


.validate-input {
    position: relative;
}
  
.alert-validate::before {
    content: attr(data-validate);
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 70%;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #c80000;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 4px 25px 5px 10px;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    right: 12px;
    pointer-events: none;
  
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    color: #c80000;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    text-align: left;
  
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
  
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s;
    transition: opacity 0.4s;
}
  
.alert-validate::after {
    content: "\f12a";
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    color: #c80000;
    font-size: 18px;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    right: 18px;
}
  
/*.alert-validate:hover:before {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
  
  @media (max-width: 992px) {
    .alert-validate::before {
      visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;
    }
}*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Login</title>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">


<meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow">
<script nonce="fd7f5276-ea45-4ec3-a649-6b2a49191c48">(function(w,d){!function(a,e,t,r){a.zarazData=a.zarazData||{},a.zarazData.executed=[],a.zaraz={deferred:[]},a.zaraz.q=[],a.zaraz._f=function(e){return function(){var t=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);a.zaraz.q.push({m:e,a:t})}};for(const e of["track","set","ecommerce","debug"])a.zaraz[e]=a.zaraz._f(e);a.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",(()=>{var t=e.getElementsByTagName(r)[0],z=e.createElement(r),n=e.getElementsByTagName("title")[0];for(n&&(a.zarazData.t=e.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].text),a.zarazData.x=Math.random(),a.zarazData.w=a.screen.width,a.zarazData.h=a.screen.height,a.zarazData.j=a.innerHeight,a.zarazData.e=a.innerWidth,a.zarazData.l=a.location.href,a.zarazData.r=e.referrer,a.zarazData.k=a.screen.colorDepth,a.zarazData.n=e.characterSet,a.zarazData.o=(new Date).getTimezoneOffset(),a.zarazData.q=[];a.zaraz.q.length;){const e=a.zaraz.q.shift();a.zarazData.q.push(e)}z.defer=!0;for(const e of[localStorage,sessionStorage])Object.keys(e).filter((a=>a.startsWith("_zaraz_"))).forEach((t=>a.zarazData["z_"+t.slice(7)]=JSON.parse(e.getItem(t))));z.referrerPolicy="origin",z.src="/cdn-cgi/zaraz/s.js?z="+btoa(encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(a.zarazData))),t.parentNode.insertBefore(z,t)}))}(w,d,0,"script");})(window,document);</script></head>

<body>
<div class="limiter">
<div class="container-login100">
<div class="wrap-login100 p-t-50 p-b-90">
<form class="login100-form validate-form flex-sb flex-w">

<span class="login100-form-title p-b-51">
Login
</span>

<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-16" data-validate="É preciso um Usuario">
<input class="input100" type="text" name="Usuario" placeholder="Usuario">
<span class="focus-input100"></span>
</div>

<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-16" data-validate="Senha é necessária">
<input class="input100" type="password" name="Senha" placeholder="Senha">
<span class="focus-input100"></span>
</div>

<div class="flex-sb-m w-full p-t-3 p-b-24">
<div class="contact100-form-checkbox">
<input class="input-checkbox100" id="ckb1" type="checkbox" name="Lembre-me">
<label class="label-checkbox100" for="ckb1">
Lembre-me
</label>
</div>

<div>
<a href="#" class="txt1">
Esqueci a senha
</a>
</div>

</div>
<div class="container-login100-form-btn m-t-17">
<button class="login100-form-btn">
Login
</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="dropDownSelect1"></div>

<div class="container-register100-form-btn m-t-17">
<button class="register100-form-btn">
Registrar
</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="dropDownSelect1"></div>

<!--
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-23581568-13"></script>
<script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());

      gtag('config', 'UA-23581568-13');
    </script>
<script defer src="https://static.cloudflareinsights.com/beacon.min.js/v652eace1692a40cfa3763df669d7439c1639079717194" integrity="sha512-Gi7xpJR8tSkrpF7aordPZQlW2DLtzUlZcumS8dMQjwDHEnw9I7ZLyiOj/6tZStRBGtGgN6ceN6cMH8z7etPGlw==" data-cf-beacon='{"rayId":"709ac5144d1b4d35","token":"cd0b4b3a733644fc843ef0b185f98241","version":"2021.12.0","si":100}' crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: also, I mark everything related to js as comment because thats not my part in this project

Comment: Do you mean Java, or Java _Script_? They are two totally different programming languages.

Comment: java script (I did't even know that u can implement java in HTML/CSS actually)